# How do I get to generate an executable from C++ files using a Python script?

Tags: python, c++, compilation, exe, executable

I have all my `.cpp` and `.hpp` files and I need to generate an .exe file from them (so my program works on Windows) with a `compile.py` file.

I need to code the `compile.py` file.

How should I do that please?

Already took a look at py2exe and PyInstaller, but I believe this is for python files only, not C++ files. Thanks

Comment: If you just want to compile the c++ files, use a make file

Comment: You don't need any `compile.py`, you need a compilation toolchain.

Comment: It's a school assignment, and that's what my teacher is asking for. I'd have used a makefile if I could.. :( @SPYBUG96 and VTT

Comment: @iNukeLaPeste Call GCC or whatever you use to compile the C++ code with from the python script

Comment: You can try [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266).

Comment: Are you trying to compile a python module or what could possibly be the purpose of such an assignment? But the again a module wouldn't be an .exe... Maybe you are supposed to use a specific build system based on python?

Comment: About the best you can do it run your C++ compiler and linker from a Python script (or perhaps run `make` to handle those things at a higher level). In such a situation, you'll essentially just be using Python to launch other non-Python processes—so you might want to consider using a shell scripting language instead.

Comment: @eukaryota we're corrected by a bot, who will launch the compile.py script, and the bot is supposed to then have a .dot exe file.

Comment: @iNukeLaPeste In that case this sounds more like its simply a technical limitation of this bot and you are probably expected to do what others have recommended. However you would still need to know which compiler exactly is available on the bot's system. Also such a bot being able to start processes like this sounds like a security issue to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a C++ compiler, not a `compile.py` file. If you REALLY need to use Python, use either `subprocess` (better) or `os.system` to call command line commands:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run('your C++ compiler command')

import os
os.system('compiler command')
```

But it would be much simpler to do it from the command line, directly executing the compile command.